# Apply same styling on multiple elements in component

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

```
const GreenRow = styled.div`
  background-color: green;
`
const RedRow = styled.div`
  background-color: red;
`
const YellowRow = styled.div`
  background-color: yellow;
`
const GreyRow = styled.div`
  background-color: grey;
`

const MyComponent = () =>
  <div>
    <GreenRow>Green row</GreenRow>
    <div>Blue row</div>
    <RedRow>Red row</RedRow>
    <YellowRow>Yellow row</YellowRow>
    <GreyRow>Grey row</GreyRow>
  </div>
```

I'm using `styled-components` to style elements in a component.

I want to apply a repeated styling (e.g. `font-weight`) on some elements in a component. Some of these component are already styled with `styled-component`, so this would be some kind of "second dimension" styling.

For example, if I could define styling with a certain classname, I could then apply that classname to each of those elements. But as [I've understood](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1180), `styled-components` don't return any classname. And I don't want to start defining styles in other files than the component itself.

Another thought is to render styling with styled-component's `css` library (see code below) and include it in every applicable styled-component definition. But then I would need to convert some elements to styled-components just for this purpose (as they aren't styled otherwise).

```
const FontWeight = css`
  font-weight: 600;
`
```

What would be the most succinct way to apply this "second dimension" styling?

Comment: It appears as though you're defining custom HTML elements. Why not simply craft rows that have shared classes? Like instead of `<GreenRow>Green row</GreenRow>`, you could use `<div class="green row">Green row</div>`, and then set the shared styling on `.row`, and the unique styling on `.green`?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear about this, but I would love to still be using `styled-components`.

Comment: You can still apply the same concept with `${props => props.component_name && css }`.

Comment: Interesting! Could you provide that solution as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can interpolate a function into the template literal, which gets passed the `props` of the component with `${props => props.component_name && css` ... `}`.

In the following, I hook into `Row` and add some additional styling for `Green`:

```
import styled, { css } from styled-components

const Row = styled.div`
  /* Generic row styling */
  font-weight: 600;

  /* Unique row styling */
  ${props => props.Green && css`
    background: green;
  `}

`
```

Note that you'll additionally need to import `css`!

Now all you have to do is render the row with the additional property when you want a green one:

```
render(
  <div>
    <Row>Normal Row</Row>
    <Row Green>Green Row</Row>
  </div>
);
```

The green row will inherit all of the styling of the regular rows, and also inherit the rules that are unique to that specific element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great answer! I think this technique should be described in styled-components docs!